# How to keep logged in facebook with unity SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

We are trying to keep the same user after closing the application in iOS. We want to keep logged in with the same Facebook user, even if that user has logged out in the Facebook app of the device or another one is logged in. We are using Facebook SDK for Unity 3D.

We are trying to do it this way:

- The first time that the user is logged we saved the response (json) of the FB.GetAuthResponse method.
- We close (kill) the application.
- The next time, when we run the application in the FB.Init method we use the auth response as third parameter.

These steps don't work for us. Is there any way to start login process with the last facebook user who used the application (we're trying to do the same behaviour as in Candy Crush).

Thanks!
Best Regards.

Comment: Yesterday, I integrate facebook sdk in my project and Implement login functionality. I did nothing to save user login info (response). Everything is working, when user kills the app he/she doesnt have to login to the facebook again. I just called fb.init on app start and fb.login fucntion when user press login button. nothing else...

If you share, you facebook app setting (iOS native app) and project setting here. I'll compare it with mine and will let you know

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, but maybe we don't explain it well. In our app we want to keep logged in with the same Facebook user, even if that user has logged out in the Facebook app of the device or another one is logged in. We tried what you said but when we call the FB.login function it gets the current FB user (or if the user has logged out then he/she has to enter his password in FB again). Have you tried these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old unanswered question.  This answer applies to the version 7.9.4 of the facebook SDK for Unity3d.

The Facebook SDK will remember if the user is logged in, there's no need to try to save that yourself.  After FB.Init(), check FB.IsLoggedIn.  If it's true just call FB.Mobile.RefreshCurrentAccessToken() and you're good to go.